# Swiper Cards on Ionic Vue changes on reloading

Tags: swiper.js, ionic-vue

When using Ionic/Vue with swiper to create cards the site initially loads correctly. But after refreshing the cards somehow 'unfold'.

See images [Cards unfold correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en4ID.png)
[Cards unfold incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQUx2.png)

Strangely swiper works fine without ion-router-outlet but does not work in combination with ion-router-outlet.

I've created a dressed down version of the offical [Swiper website](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/8xwgf7?file=/src/App.vue):

index.ts:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from '@ionic/vue-router';
import { RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
import MainPage from '../views/Main.vue'

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: MainPage
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <ion-app>
    <ion-router-outlet />
  </ion-app>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet } from '@ionic/vue';
</script>
```

Main.vue

```
<template>
  <ion-page>
  <swiper
    :effect="'cards'"
    :grabCursor="true"
    :modules="[EffectCards]"
    class="mySwiper"
  >
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide><swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</ion-page>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { IonPage, IonHeader, IonToolbar, IonTitle, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue';  // Import Swiper Vue.js components
  import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';

  // Import Swiper styles
  import 'swiper/css';

  import 'swiper/css/effect-cards';
  // import required modules
  import { EffectCards } from 'swiper';

</script>
```

Css:

```
#app { height: 100% }
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper {
  width: 240px;
  height: 320px;
}

.swiper-slide {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 18px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(1n) {
  background-color: rgb(206, 17, 17);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 255);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: rgb(10, 184, 111);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: rgb(211, 122, 7);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(5n) {
  background-color: rgb(118, 163, 12);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(6n) {
  background-color: rgb(180, 10, 47);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(7n) {
  background-color: rgb(35, 99, 19);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(8n) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 68, 255);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(9n) {
  background-color: rgb(218, 12, 218);
}

.swiper-slide:nth-child(10n) {
  background-color: rgb(54, 94, 77);
}
```

For the full code see [github](https://github.com/DuriDeux/Ionic-Vue-Swiper-Error)

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I have the same problem. From what I found the { EffectCards } are not getting applied properly to the swiper instance when coming from another route.